# Could the vision of Star Wars's galactic core worlds be even remotely plausible

Tags: star-wars

From my, albeit limited, understanding, the galactic core is nothing more than super-massive black holes where nothing has absolutely any chance of living, ever. Yet in *Star Wars*, the core worlds and, if I'm not mistaken, deep core worlds  are the most rich and prosperous of worlds.

What I do understand is that you do want to be somewhere in the "middle" area of the galaxy. Everything is closer by and there is more of everything. All worlds here, provided they are class M (or any other class that would be perfect for some sort of life-form) would be incredibly favored compared to outer rim worlds.

But the question is: Could worlds very near the core actually be livable ? How about within the core ?

Comment: *Star Wars* is not set in **the** galaxy. Does **every** galaxy have a super-massive black hole at its core, including galaxies long ago and far away?

Comment: @user14111: Wikipedia says "There is general consensus that supermassive black holes exist in the centers of **most** galaxies" so I suppose not.  But my understanding is that the central black hole isn't really why galactic cores are thought to be uninhabitable.

Comment: However, I'm not sure that primary canon actually says there are any inhabited worlds in the very center of the galaxy?  When they talk in the movies about "core" worlds as opposed to "rim" worlds, they might just mean worlds, say, less than a third of the way out from the center - well into the inhabitable region but still nearer to the center than to the rim.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of question is off-topic for this site. We only allow scientific explanations if they are constrained within the universe of the movie. You're asking if such a thing is possible in *real life*, which is outside our scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the maps seen in [Star Wars: The Essential Atlas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas), the "core" worlds are those that are relatively close to the Galactic core. Their wealth comes not only from mineral wealth but also the relative ease of travel (multiple major hyperspace routes have been plotted between them) and the relatively short distances between them, facilitating high volumes of commerce.

Note that in the original Star Wars Atlas maps, within the core proper (described as the "*deep core*") there were no listed planets. The latest version of this map, however, adds a few planets that seem to exist well within the deep core.

[image]
**Star Wars: Atlas (non-Canon)**

[image]
**Star Wars: Updated Atlas (Canon)**

Comment: `The Deep Core was a region of the galaxy that lay at its very heart. A densely packed mass of stars and planets, the Deep Core was dangerous to navigate. `

Comment: Whoah. You answered with non-canon Legends material? **I WANT TO GO BACK TO MY NON MY NON-ALTERNATE UNIVERSE**

Comment: @DVK - You make it sound like I'm some sort of Star Wars canon-Nazi...

Comment: @Richard - No nerf nuggets for you!!!

Comment: @DVK - Remind me to work Skippy the Jedi Droid into my next SW answer.

Comment: @Richard - [Noooooooooooooooooooooo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GryXjVHfewY)!

Comment: Well the planet Prakith is located in the Deep Core and according to the relevant wiki does exist in the current canon as well as legends

Comment: @IG_42 - Indeed, and a few others such as Tython, Kalist and Byss (which seems insanely close to the middle).